# SVG canvas too big, android default browser only

Tags: android, svg, android-browser

I've made a mobile website, which has a SVG file which acts as a fancy HR. We choose svg because it scales good.

It works as expected in all (mobile)browsers, **apart from Android's Stock browser**, which produces the screenshot (all other browsers only show the green part of the screenshot, which is good).

- The designer saved this image with a full green background (select all, make green)
- I've css-ed it something like this: `#wrap > img{ background: red; }`

In the Android browser the SVG is 100% screen **height**:
[image: image screenshot android canvas problem]
If it helps, [this is the content of the svg](http://pastebin.com/0WxR24b9).

I have no clue what to look for. The SVG seems fine, other svg's always load as expected, what makes this one different?

*"What have you tried?"* Not much since I don't have a clue where I start.
- The svg has been resaved (No effect)
- css `#wrap > img{ height: auto;}` (no effect)
- css `#wrap > img{ max-height: 60px;}` (makes the #Wrap 60 height, the SVG pushed together)
- Took it through a 'svg optimiser' (no changes)

Comment: Can you rephrase the sentence "In all browsers, I see a green image with the content, in the Android browser is 100% screen height:"?  It is not making sense to me.  What exactly happens on the other browsers?

Comment: Rephrased it. In all other browsers everything works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After some time, the solution:*

If you open the SVG in a text editor, the first part will have something like:

```
viewBox="0 0 190 70"
```

If you add `width="190` and `height="70"` after it, the problem will disappear. This will create some small difficulties when you want to resize, but the major problem is solved:

```
viewBox="0 0 190 70" width="190" height="70"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution to SVG bounding box issues has been to edit the first section to have `width="100%" height="100%"` instead of specified values.